# Change CSS property of element when time changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I'm building a toy job scheduling system using meteor.

Here's the controller where I pass a "shifts" collection:

```
angular.module('eamorr').controller('EamorrCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor', function ($scope, $meteor) {
    $scope.shifts = $meteor.collection(Shifts);
    ...
}]);
```

... to my `.ng.html`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="shift in shifts">
   ...
   <td>{{shift.unixTime_start*1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td> 
   ...
</tr>
```

Now, when `shift.unixTime_start` is less than the current time, I want the whole row to have `background-color:orange` and when `shift.unixTime_start` is greater than the current time, I want the whole row to have `background-color:green`.

Can anyone give me a tip as to how to do this neatly, cleanly and concisely?

I've been looking at doing a load of ng-if statements, etc. Do I *have* to use an interval? Check every 5 seconds and update the table accordingly? This doesn't seem the right way to me...

Comment: I would do this in the controller. Adding a new $scope function getStyle(shift) which does the check in the controller and the in the html set the return value into the style tag of the td element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

```
Template.shifts.onCreated(function () {
  this.now = new ReactiveVar(moment());
  this.timerId = null;

  let oneSecond = moment().add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute');
  Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
    this.timerId = Meteor.setInterval(() => {
      this.now.set(moment());
    }, 5000)
  }, oneSecond.get('milliseconds'));
});

Template.shifts.helpers({
  timeColor: function (unix) {
    let time = moment(unix);
    if (moment.isBefore(time, this.now.get())) {
      return '#FF00FF';
    } else if (moment.isAfter(time, this.now.get())) {
      return '#FF0000';
    } else {
      return '#003366';
    }
  }
});

Template.shifts.onDestroyed(function () {
  Meteor.clearInterval(this.timerId);
})
```

Then in your template

```
<tr style="background-color: {{ timeColor shift.unixTime_start }};">
  <td>{{ shift.unixTime_start }}</td>
</tr>
```